# Callback functionality for futures from different threadpools

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, asynccallback, completable-future

I am currently working on a functionality where I need to make a callback after, lets say `'n'` number of threads are completed (or failed). Amongst the `'n'` sub-tasks, `n-1` tasks will be submitted to one particular thread pool and I will have access to all these `n-1` futures.

I have no issue in making the callback upon completion of all futures. I intend to pass an atomic monitor to each of these `n-1` tasks and initiate the callback basing on some count.

Now i'm stuck dealing with the other single thread. Basically this thread is a different execution workflow. As per the functionality after initiating these `(n-1)` tasks/threads, I will make a separate call to a different application (to perform some long running task) and will exit. Once the other application is done with its computation, it will push its results through a different end point.

So, while the separate service is pushing its result, I have to maintain some sort of context to club all these sub-tasks together. I could solve this using a singleton hashmap or a local cache (guava caches) using a unique ID and using the atomic monitor (shared amongst all the sub-tasks).

Before that I wanted to know the pros and cons of this approach. Also, I would really appreciate, if you can propose some sort of design pattern or framework for  implementing this workflow in an elegant manner.